# .NET DateTime adding localtime offset when being serialized?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, json.net, utc

I have a timestamp stored in my database:

```
2019-05-17 15:33:23.137
```

I create a `DateTime` object for this timestamp.

I create a DTO for this DateTime

```
public MyDateDTO(DateTime date){
  this.date = date;
}
```

Regardless of what timezone my system is set to, I can see that when I return this DTO the date is as I expect (I tried both est and utc, in both cases I see that `DateTime.Ticks = 636937040031370000`. However, it seems like when this DTO gets serialized an offset somehow seems to be getting added.

So if I check my browser network tools and set system timezone to UTC, I see the timestamp `2019-05-17T15:33:23.137Z` received by my browser. However, if I set my system timezone to EST, then the timestamp `2019-05-17T19:33:23.137Z` is received by my browser.

How do i stop this offset from being added? I can see that the timestamp is unconverted as I expect when I return the dto from my controller function, so I assume it must be done somewhere in the middleware?

I am able to workaround it by converting the calling `ToLocalTime` on the `DateTime` object to counteract the offset (i think?) but I would prefer just to exclude this offset in the first place

Comment: Not sure if i understand you correct but this might be the thing you're looking for? 
[DateTimeOffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: DateTime has a property `Kind` which could be `Utc`, `Local` or `Unspecified`. If your DateTime is of kind `Unspecified` (Database does not store a time zone) serializers often "guess" the right time zone. Make sure, your DateTime, you send to the browser has a `Kind`specified.

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen this solved the issue. Thanks!